# (ReactJS, Redux) Edit page, cannot receive the state object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am working on the Edit page w/ Redux.

I really don't understand why **JourneyForm.js** could not get the `journey state` that was given from **EditJourneyPage.js** even though I toss the attribute `(journey={this.props.journey})` like this.
when I checked `journey.jourID === props.match.params.id;` by console, it works fine. I guess `.find` function can return the "journey" object.

Please help me to resolve it.

**EditJourneyPage.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import JourneyForm from './JourneyForm';
import { editJourney } from '../actions/journies';

class EditJourneyPage extends React.Component {
    onSubmit = (journey) => {
        this.props.dispatch(editJourney(journey.jourID, journey));
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <JourneyForm 
                    journey={this.props.journey}
                    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                />
                <button>Remove</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        journey: state.journies.find((journey) => {
            return journey.jourID === props.match.params.id;
        })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditJourneyPage);
```

**JourneyForm.js**

```js
import React, { Compoent } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';
import { SingleDatePicker, DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';

class JourneyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: props.journey ? props.journey.title : '',
            note: props.journey ? props.journey.note : '',
            startDate: props.journey ? moment(props.journey.startDate) : moment(),
            endDate: props.journey ? moment(props.journey.endDate) : moment(),
            userID: props.auth ? props.auth.uid : '',
            state: 'A',
            focusedInput: null,
            error: ''
        }
    }


    onTitleChange = (e) => {
        const title = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({ title }));
    }
    onNoteChange = (e) => {
        const note = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({ note }));
    }
    onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
           this.setState(() => ({ startDate, endDate }));
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!this.state.title && this.state.startDate && this.state.endDate) {
            this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Please fill the all blanks'}));
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({ error: '' }));
            this.props.onSubmit({
                title: this.state.title,
                startDate: this.state.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                endDate: this.state.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                userID: this.state.userID,
                state: this.state.state,           
                note: this.state.note
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Title" 
                        autoFocus 
                        value={this.state.title} 
                        onChange={this.onTitleChange}
                    />
                    <DateRangePicker
                        startDate={this.state.startDate}
                        startDateId="startDate"
                        endDate={this.state.endDate}
                        endDateId="endDate"
                        onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
                        focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
                        onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })}
                        withPortal
                    />
                    <textarea
                        placeholder="Add a note for your journey (optional)"
                        value={this.state.note}
                        onChange={this.onNoteChange}
                    />
                    <button>Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }`enter code here`
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(JourneyForm)
```

Comment: How does your `state.journies` looks like?

Comment: what's the type of `jourID` ?

Comment: Try to `console.log(this.props.journey)` in your `JourneyForm.js` `render()` i suppose you'll get undefined at first render then you'll get the object at the second.

Comment: export const startAddJourney = (journey) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/journey/addMyjourney`, journey).then((ref) => {
            dispatch(addJourney({
                jourID: ref.data,
                ...journey
            }));
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })
    }
}

Comment: this is the action (journies.js) so the jourId is from api call. and the type of it is int which is automatically increased by DB. @Dyo Yes, first time it is undefined because it made on "Create Page" . However, I couldn't get the object second time when I access the "Edit PAge" . I really confused...